# Excel VBA Error when I try to reference a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Can anyone suggest why uncommenting the 'bar = Worksheets("Communicators")' line would cause this function to fail and return #Value.  Note that the exact same reference exists in the first concatRng line and works as expected without error at that point.

```
Function concatRng(rng As Range) As String
     
     Dim c As Range
     Dim foo As Range
     Dim bar As Worksheet
     
'    bar = Worksheets("Communicators")
     
'    foo = bar.Range("A3:O3")
     
     concatRng = Worksheets("Communicators").Name & "|" & rng.Columns.Count
     
     For Each c In rng
          concatRng = concatRng & " - " & c.Value
     Next
     
     concatRng = concatRng & "|"
     
End Function
```

Comment: That should be `Set bar = Worksheets("Communicators")` since it is an object.

Comment: You should be aware that, whilst VBA allows the name of a function to also be used as a variable withing the function body, this practise makes for code that is difficult to read and consequently prone to errors.

Comment: @freeflow is that not how you designate the value that will be returned by the function?

Comment: I'm referring to this ' concatRng = concatRng & " - " & c.Value'. The second use of concatRng is not a recursive function call but the use of the value stored in the return vector concatRng.  See the response by @VBasic2008 for a much better way to write the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the SET command. VBA requires that object assignments be preceded by the Set command. Therefore you should have written:

```
Set bar = Worksheets("Communicators")

Set foo = bar.Range("A3:O3")
```

With respect to the first assignment, it is a String expression, which is not an object in VBA.

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

### Concat Range

```vb
Function ConcatRng(ByVal rng As Range) As String
     
    Dim Result As String
    
    Result = rng.Worksheet.Name & "|" & rng.Columns.Count
    
    Dim cell As Range
    
    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        Result = Result & " - " & cell.Value
    Next cell
    
    Result = Result & "|"
    
    ConcatRng = Result
     
End Function
```